# How do I resolve the eslint rule "require-atomic-updates"?

Tags: eslint

I often understand the reasoning behind the rules and how to resolve them but this one I do not understand how to resolve.

Worth mentioning is that I've read the [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-atomic-updates) for the rule but it doesnät

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
Possible race condition: `req.meta.pageImage` might be reassigned based on an outdated value of `req.meta.pageImage`
```

And this is the code that triggers it:

```js
async function retailerAction(req, res) {
  const { groupId } = req.params;
  let group;
  try {
    const result = await trinidad.jupiter.callAsync({
      method: 'GET',
      path: `/marketplace/groups/${groupId}?include=group.imageId,group.name,group.description`,
      req
    });
    group = result.group;
  } catch (e) {}

  if (group.imageId) {
    req.meta.pageImage = group.imageId; // <--- error
  } else {
    req.meta.pageImage = null; // <--- error
  }

  req.renderModel = {  // <--- error
    title: { text: group.name },
    metaDescription: {
      description: normalizeDraftjsText(group.description)
    }
  };

  routeHandler(req, res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand it 100% yet, but I'm dealing with the same problem and reading the docs, and pretty sure it's triggered by your assigning the mutable `let group` BEFORE your await statement.

Try assigning it as `const group` after that `await`, and adjust your other code as needed.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Use `// eslint-disable-next-line require-atomic-updates` above the lines causing errors if you know req is not possibly being updated while you are awaiting for your trinidad.jupiter.callAsync() call to finish.

This rule is a bit excessive in my opinion, but essentially the reason behind it is to prevent you from reading a mutable value (i.e. using an object or its properties, using an array or its elements, using `req` in your case, etc.), letting some other code run that may or may not update that mutable value by using the `await` or `yeild` keywords, and then making updates to the same mutable value you read before (i.e updating/adding a property to an object, updating/adding an element to an array, updating/adding property to `req` in your case, etc.).

The reason they want to prevent you from doing this is to avoid the case where you read the mutable value (call this "value pre-await/yeild"); while you're awaiting a promise or yeilding, the mutable value is updated (call this updated value "value during-await/yeild"); and you incorrectly update the mutable value (call this updated value "value post-await/yeild") based on the outdated value you read before awaiting or yeilding (i.e. "value pre-await/yeild") since the mutable value should have been updated based on its current value at the point you are making the update, which would have been "value during-await/yeild".

Here is a code snippet as an example of what I mean:

```js
async function codeThatUpdatesMutableValue(mutableValue) {
  mutableValue.timeSpanInSeconds = 60;
}

async function runMainThread() {
  const mutableValueToUpdate = { timeSpanInSeconds: 0, timeSpanInMinutes: 0 };
  const timeSpanInSeconds = mutableValueToUpdate.timeSpanInSeconds;

  /* while awaiting and letting code that mutates mutableValueToUpdate to run, 
  * mutableValueToUpdate.timeSpanInSeconds is set to 60
  */
  await codeThatUpdatesMutableValue(mutableValueToUpdate);  

  /* at this point timeSpanInSeconds is still 0 since you read mutableValueToUpdate.timeSpanInSeconds
   * before it was updated to 60, but the current value of mutableValueToUpdate.timeSpanInSeconds is
   * 60. So we are incorrectly setting mutableValueToUpdate.timeSpanInMinutes to 0 (i.e. 0/60 because 
   * there are 60 seconds in a minute) instead of 1 (i.e. 60/60 because there are 60 seconds in a 
   * minute) because timeSpanInSeconds is outdated.
   */
  mutableValueToUpdate.timeSpanInMinutes = timeSpanInSeconds/60;

  console.log(mutableValueToUpdate) // { timeSpanInSeconds: 60, timeSpanInMinutes: 0 }
}

runMainThread()
```